# Preview is accurate, but export / render is overexposed / too bright when there's a layer on top

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm editing a small video and have already added several *Text* strips into an above layer. The problem is that now for some reason, the moment my render hits a place where there's text on the video, the brightness goes way up. Here is a [small little video to explain the problem](https://vid.me/0szP).

I know that the variables are unreadable on the video, so I added detailed screenshots to this post.

[image: Settings]

[image: Materials]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things occur to me:

1. **Your Materials.** I noticed your materials in the second screenshot. Why use an *Emit* value instead of cranking up the *Intensity* and checking *Shading > Shadeless*? This could bleed over and cause the brightening.
2. **Text in the VSE.** Is your text animated? Does it move or change? If it doesn't, you should really consider using *Text* strips instead of *Scene* strips. To add a *Text* strip, key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then mouse over to *Effect Strip > Text*. In the *VSE's Properties panel* (key <kbd>N</kbd> to toggle open/close) make sure *Edit Strip > Alpha Over* is selected in the *Blend:* drop down menu. This will make sure that only the text is displaying. Lastly, go to *VSE Properties panel > Effect Strip > Text:* and enter your text.

Comment: I actually made progress on my own. It turns out all my text's (as seperate scenes) still had their Shading > Alpha set to Sky. I believe this makes it so there's an actual background behind the object, right? So this could reflect some of the light that my text is emitting. Therefor ending up with some faint light on parts that are supposed to be transparent. And they get added up to the full scene in the composition. Fixed it by turning the alpha to Transparent.

Comment: Possibly. If that worked, then I'm very happy for you. Also, if you liked my answer, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Enjoy your +25 :P